# vscode Path to the pylint linter is invalid

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am running VS Code on Windows 7 with a virtual environment (path `/c/Users/xxxxxxx/Envs/tutorial`). [will soon be Windows 10]

I keep getting the following popup error in the bottom left of the screen:

```
Path to the pylint linter is invalid
(/c/Users/xxxxxxx/Envs/tutorial/Scripts/pylint)
Source: Python (Extension)
```

I have selected the Python interpreter using `ctrl+shift+p` > `Python:select interpreter`.
If I open a terminal and run:

```
$ "${PWD}/Scripts/pylint.exe" --version
```

The output is:

```
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
(tutorial)
```

That seems fine.

Is there something I should set in `settings.json` to set the path for the linter for this virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you installed Pylint into the virtual environment you are using. If that's true then you do not need to specify `"python.linting.pylintPath"` and can instead rely on `python -m pylint` working.

Comment: That was really helpful, @brettcannon.  I had installed Pylint into the virtual environment.  I have now removed it from there and put in as a global Python installation, and that seems to have cleared the pop-up error.

Comment: Actual working solution - slightly different.  @brettcannon  I ended up reinstalling Pylint in the environment I was using, and from `Preferences|Settings|search for "pylint"`, put the absolute path of the environment installation in the `Python > Linting: Pylint Path`, which must be the `"python.linting.pylintPath"` setting. That has been working well. For some reason, the linting wasn't working after I had installed Pylint in my global Python installation. The downside is that I will have to change this when working with other environments, but at least it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install "**Pylance**" and "**Python**" Extension and reload or restart your VSCode.
Hope this will solve your problem.